# Google bigquery python client library SQL select regex error

Tags: python, sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a google bigquery table using the regex from [this blog post](https://kozikow.com/2016/07/01/top-pandas-functions-used-in-github-repos/#comment-99#Methodology). Here it is, slightly modified:

`` pd\.([^”,\.\(\,\`) \’:\[\]\/\\={}]*) ``

[regex101 example of its usage](https://regex101.com/r/EBR9dg/1)

It does not, however, work in my google bigquery python client SQL query:

```
query_results = client.run_sync_query(
"""
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(SPLIT(content, '\n'),
                 r'pd\.([^”,\.\(\,\`) \’:\[\]\/\\={}]*)')
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:github_extracts.contents_py]
LIMIT 10
""")

query_results.run()

data = query_results.fetch_data()
data
```

> BadRequest: BadRequest: 400 Failed to parse regular expression "pd.([^”,.(\,`) \’:[]/\={}]*)": invalid escape sequence: \’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that BigQuery uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2) library for its regex operations.

If you try the same regex but using the **golang** flavor you will see the exact same [error](https://regex101.com/r/EBR9dg/4) (golang also uses re2).

So maybe if you just remove the escaping of the `'` character you'll already have it working for you (as I tested here it seemed to work properly).

Another issue that you might find is that the result of the `SPLIT` operation is an `ARRAY`. That means that BigQuery won't process your query saying that the signature of `REGEXP_EXTRACT` does not allow `ARRAY<STRING>` as input. You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead:

```
"""
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(content, r'.*(\\n)', ''),
                 r'pd\.([^”,\.\(\,\`) ’:\[\]\/\\={}]*)')
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:github_extracts.contents_py]
LIMIT 10
"""
```

The character "\n" is replaced by "" in this operation and the result is a `STRING`.

Comment: Cheers @Will, I appreciate the solution and explanation. The `REGEXP_EXTRACT ` appears to be working on the array, but I will experiment your method should I find that error.